# How to delete a specific row by using it's row id ina muddatagrid in Blazor

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, hybrid-mobile-app

I need to delete a specific row when I click it in muddatagrid. I implemented a function but it is passing the item name. So it will delete all the items which have that name. How can I do that by taking the row id? Then I can delete only the selected record.

```
      <MudDataGrid Items="@Elements" Hover="true" Striped="true" Dense="true" FixedHeader="true" >
              <Columns>
                 <Column T="Menuitemlist" StickyLeft="true">
                     <CellTemplate>
                           <MudIconButton OnClick="@(() => RemoveItem(@context.Item))" Color="@Color.Default" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Delete" />
                      </CellTemplate>
                  </Column>
                  <Column T="Menuitemlist" Field="ItemName" Title="Name" />
                  <Column T="Menuitemlist" Title="%">
               <CellTemplate>
                     <MudNumericField @bind-Value="DiscountValue" Style="height:30px" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Step=".5M" />
               </CellTemplate>
                    </Column>
                    <Column T="Menuitemlist" Title="Qty">
                         <CellTemplate>
                           <MudNumericField @bind-Value="DecimalValue" Style="height:30px"  Variant="Variant.Outlined" Step=".5M" />
                         </CellTemplate>
                     </Column>
                     <Column T="Menuitemlist" Field="OptionalSalesPrice" Title="Price" />
                     <Column T="Menuitemlist" Title="Total" />
                  </Columns>
       </MudDataGrid>
                           

  private void RemoveItem(Menuitemlist x)
{
    //orderitems.RemoveAt(0);
    orderitems = orderitems.Where(u => u.ItemName != x.ItemName).ToList();
    Elements = orderitems;
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since the code is not a miminally reproducible example, I provide it:

```
@using Models

<MudItem xs="12" Class="pt-0">
   <div id="unique_id_scroll_section" class="ma-0" style="height:200px;overflow: auto">
   @{
       for(int i=0; i < ElementsList.Count(); i++)
       {
           ElementsList[i].ID = i;
       }
   }
   <MudDataGrid Items="@ElementsList" Hover="true" Striped="true" Dense="true">
          <Columns>
                <Column T="Element" StickyLeft="true">
                     <CellTemplate>
                          <MudIconButton OnClick="@(() => PrcdBtnClick(@context.Item))" Color="@Color.Default" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Delete" />
                     </CellTemplate>
                </Column>
                <Column T="Element" Field="Name" />
                
            </Columns>
    </MudDataGrid>
   </div> 
</MudItem>

@code { 

    private List<Element> ElementsList = new List<Element>(){new Element("Uranium"), new Element("Radium"), new Element("Cobalt"),new Element("Uranium")};

    private void PrcdBtnClick(Element x)
    {
        ElementsList = ElementsList.Where(u => u.ID != x.ID).ToList();
    }

}
```

Element.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace Models
{
    public class Element
    {
        public string Group { get; set; } = "Group";
        public int Position { get; set; } = 1;
        public string Name { get; set; } = "Plutonium";
        public int Number { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("small")]
        public string Sign { get; set; } = "Piesces";
        public double Molar { get; set; } = 6.9;
        public IList<int> Electrons { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{Sign} - {Name}";
        }

        public Element(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public int ID {set; get;} = 0;
    }
}
```

Working example: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wkcHuQGWouimCrOC

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75625118/16241720 Can you please suggest a solution for this question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75672361/16241720 this is a different question. can you suggest a solution for this