# How to get summation of values of a datagrid in mudblazor

Tags: c#, .net, datagrid, blazor, mudblazor

How to get the summation of values of a Datagrid using mudblazor. The total will be calculated by multiplying the unit price by quantity and how to give a discount and get the total. Then have to truncate it to 2 decimal places.
how to get sum of these truncatedtotal and need to print it in below mud paper?

```
<MudDataGrid Items="@Elements" Hover="true" Striped="true" Dense="true">
           <Columns>
              <Column T="Menuitemlist" StickyLeft="true" Class="removeicon">
                       <CellTemplate>
                               <MudIconButton OnClick="@(() => RemoveItem(@context.Item))" Color="@Color.Default" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Delete" />
                       </CellTemplate>
              </Column>
              <Column T="Menuitemlist" Field="ItemName" Title="Name"  />
              <Column T="Menuitemlist" Field="qty" Title="Qty" >
                        <CellTemplate>
                             <MudGrid Style="padding-left:unset;padding-right:unset">
                                     <MudItem xs="3"  Class="d-flex align-center justify-center ">
                                           <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.AddCircle" Variant="Variant.Filled" Size="Size.Small" @onclick="(() => context.Item.qty = context.Item.qty + 0.5)" />
                                      </MudItem>
                                      <MudItem xs="6"  Class="d-flex align-center justify-center pa-2">
                                              <MudTextField @bind-Value="@context.Item.qty"  Margin="Margin.Dense" Style="text-align:center"  />
                                       </MudItem>
                                       <MudItem xs="3"  Class="d-flex align-center justify-center">
                                             <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.RemoveCircle" Variant="Variant.Filled" Size="Size.Small" @onclick="(() => context.Item.qty = context.Item.qty - 0.5)" />
                                            </MudItem>
                                       </MudGrid>
                                  </CellTemplate>
                               </Column>
                               <Column T="Menuitemlist" Field="OptionalSalesPrice" Title="Price" CellStyle="text-align:right" >
                                    <CellTemplate>
                                        <MudText Typo="Typo.subtitle1">@context.Item.OptionalSalesPrice.ToString("F")</MudText>
                                    </CellTemplate>         
                                </Column>
                                <Column T="Menuitemlist" Title="%" CellStyle="text-align: right">
                                                <CellTemplate>
                                                    <MudText @bind-Value="DiscountValue" Typo="Typo.body2" >@DiscountValue</MudText>
                                                </CellTemplate>
                                            </Column>
                                    <Column T="Menuitemlist" Title="Total" CellStyle="text-align: right" >
                                                <CellTemplate>
                                                     @{
                                                        
                                                        var total = (context.Item.OptionalSalesPrice * context.Item.qty) * (1- (DiscountValue/100.00));
                                                        double truncatedtotal = Math.Round(total, 2);

                                                        double subtotal12 = 
                                                    
                                                      }
                                                    <MudText Typo="Typo.body2">

                                                        @truncatedtotal.ToString("F")
                                                    </MudText>
                                                </CellTemplate>
                                            </Column>
                                        </Columns>
                                    </MudDataGrid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use **FooterTemplate**. Here is an example:

```
<MudDataGrid Items="@LstTarea.AsQueryable()" Hover="true" Dense="true" Striped="true" Bordered="true" Style="width:fit-content;">
    <Columns>
        <PropertyColumn Property="p => p.hrs_tarea_orden" Title="#" CellStyle="text-align:right;width:50px;" />
        <TemplateColumn SortBy="p => p.hrs_tarea_nombre" Title="Tarea" CellStyle="text-align:left;" FooterStyle="text-align:right;">
            <CellTemplate>
                <a href="@string.Format("{0}?hrs_tarea={1}",_UrlHorasTarea,context.Item.hrs_tarea)">@context.Item.hrs_tarea_nombre</a>
            </CellTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                Cantidad: @context.Items.Count()
            </FooterTemplate>
        </TemplateColumn>
        <PropertyColumn Property="p => p.hrs_tarea_presupuesto" Title="Horas P." CellStyle="text-align:right;" FooterStyle="text-align:right;" Sortable="false">
            <FooterTemplate>
                @UtilsPortal.Formatear(context.Items.Sum(x => x.hrs_tarea_presupuesto))
            </FooterTemplate>
        </PropertyColumn>
        <PropertyColumn Property="p => p.hrs_tarea_avance" Title="Avance" CellStyle="text-align:right;" FooterStyle="text-align:right;" Sortable="false" Format="0.0'%'">
            <FooterTemplate>
                @(UtilsPortal.Formatear(context.Items.Sum(x => x.hrs_tarea_avance) / context.Items.Count()) + "%")
            </FooterTemplate>
        </PropertyColumn>
    </Columns>
</MudDataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the total and truncated total calculations inside the `CellTemplate` of the `MudDataGrid` you should put it inside your Model class by adding new properties. Example:

```cs
public class MenuItemList
{
    public double OptionalSalesPrice { get; set; }
    public double Qty { get; set; }
    public int DiscountValue { get; set; }

    private double Total => (OptionalSalesPrice * Qty) * (1 - (DiscountValue / 100.00));
    public double TruncatedTotal => Math.Round(Total, 2);
}
```

Then your `MudDataGrid` `Column` becomes much simpler:

```
<Column T="MenuItemList" Title="Total" CellStyle="text-align: right">
    <CellTemplate>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.body2">@context.Item.TruncatedTotal.ToString("F")</MudText>
    </CellTemplate>
</Column>
```

and also you can use `System.Linq` [Enumerable.Sum method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=net-8.0) to easily calculate the sum truncated total in your page.

```
...
<MudPaper>
    <p>Sub Total: @SubTotal</p>
    <p>Discount: @Discount</p>
    <p>Net Total: @NetTotal</p>
</MudPaper>

@code {
    ...
    private double SubTotal => Elements.Sum(e => e.TruncatedTotal);
    private double NetTotal => ...;
}
```